# Xorg starts in failsafe mode when nvidia-current is active

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I have nvidia-current installed (version 295.40-0ubuntu1) and nvidia-current-updates (version 295.49-0ubuntu0.1) running on Ubuntu 12.04. These are the latest version in Ubuntu proposed, but the problem was before the update to proposed.

The problem is that after running sudo nvidia-xconfig I get a xorg.config generated as shown at the end. When I reboot the xOrg starts but in a very low resolution (failsafe mode). This happens with or without my second HDMI screen attached (which mirrors my latop screen).

I have a Dell XPS 14z, with a NVIDIA GeForce GT 520M 1GB graphics with Optimus. I don't not have ANY issues with the same card on the same computer under Windows 7. My kernel is: 3.2.0-23.36.

Any help with this would be great, I really would like my NVIDIA driver to work.

xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 295.49  (buildmeister@swio-display-x86-rhel47-07.nvidia.com)  Tue May  1 00:54:24 PDT 2012


Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

The (EE) in /var/log/Xorg.0.log is:

```
[    10.014] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)
```

Comment: Do you see any errors `(EE)` or `Segmentation fault` in /var/log/Xorg.0.log?

Comment: Yeah, I found an (EE) to do with NVIDIA:

'[    10.014] (EE) Failed to load module "nvidia" (module does not exist, 0)'

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, check that you have the nvidia package installed.  The following command should show `ii` at the far left on the nvidia line:

```
sudo dpkg -l nvidia-current
```

Assuming you do have the nvidia package installed, I'd give the "nouveau" driver a try.  It's open source, and seems to have fewer issues than the binary one, but it's not as fast.  To try it, edit `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and change the `"Device"` `Driver` line from `"nvidia"` to `"nouveau"`.

Before restarting X, make sure `nouveau` is installed:

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

You *might* need to remove the binary driver(s) in order for "nouveau" to work:

```
sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current nvidia-current-updates
```

You may need to reboot after any of the above changes to see it working as expected (unless you are very familiar with Ubuntu kernel module (un)loading).

Btw, there are known issues with `nvidia-current`.  See [Launchpad bug #980298](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/980298).  Also, you state that `nvidia-current-updates` is 295.49, but [packages.ubuntu.com seems to think that it is 295.40](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/nvidia-current-updates).  So, you may have better luck when Ubuntu officially rolls out 295.49.  Alternatively, the Launchpad bug has a [link to a deb for 295.49](https://launchpad.net/~suraia/+archive/ppa/+build/3464331).

Comment: Thanks, I have the nouveau one running now, I have complete removed anything to do with NVIDIA. I would like to get it working, so then I can try bumblebee as at the moment, my battery life is shocking (compared to Windows) in Ubuntu

Comment: Thanks for the help, I might wait a bit and try again, other wise report a bug